# Difference between "con degli amici" and "con amici"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference

How does adding 'degli' in 2. change the meaning of 1.?

> 1. Sono stato al ristorante con amici.
> 2. Sono stato al ristorante con **degli** amici.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion

> Sono stato al ristorante con amici.

stresses the fact that the people I was with were friends, as opposed to other "categories" such as family members, coworkers and so on.

On the other hand

> Sono stato al ristorante con degli amici.

gives slightly less importance to the kind of people I was with and communicates two facts (*I went to the restaurant* and *I was with friends*) with no focus on a particular one.

Comment: This is right: It is like with _delle persone_, or _la vedova […] magra come una acciuga, con delle mani spolpate_.

Answer (score 5):

"Degli" in this context means "a certain quantity of, some", so the two examples have different meanings:

> 1. I went to the restaurant with friends
> 2. I went to the restaurant with some friends

The change in meaning is analogous as you would have in English.

Comment: Indeed, but he asked about the change of meaning. In English as in Italian, both sentences mean that I went to the restaurants and I was with some friends, but they express the same concept slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

''Con gli amici'' sounds much better than ''con amici.''

You can also use ''alcuni''... both ''degli'' and ''alcuni'' mean ''some'', whereas ''gli'' means ''the'' [in English wouldn't be OK, but in Italian is fine.]